# Amazon Web Services error tracking service - similar to airbrake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, sidekiq

Does AWS have integrated error tracking service similar to Airbrake, which can be used with Ruby on Rails application and sidekiq background jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS doesn’t offer a service like Airbrake for error tracking, but you can host yourself. Errbit (https://github.com/errbit/errbit) is open-source and has an Airbrake compliant API. There is also plenty of Airbrake competitors out there. At the moment, I’m using http://honeybadger.io for monitoring my apps.